# Does Elasticsearch curator Rollover action doesn't support Date math in the name?

Tags: elasticsearch, rollover, elasticsearch-curator

I'm trying to use the date math in the elasticsearch curator rollover action, but it seems like it doesn't support alias name as a date math like '<indexname-{now/d}>'

```
---
# Remember, leave a key empty if there is no value.  None will be a string,
# not a Python "NoneType"
#
# Also remember that all examples have 'disable_action' set to True.  If you
# want to use this action as a template, be sure to set this to False after
# copying it.
actions:
  1:
    action: rollover
    description: >-
      Rollover the index associated with alias 'indexname-{now/d}', index should be in the format of indexname-{now/d}-000001.
    options:
      disable_action: False
      name: '<indexname-{now/d}>'
      conditions:
        max_age: 1d
        max_docs: 1000000
        max_size: 50g
      extra_settings:
        index.number_of_shards: 3
        index.number_of_replicas: 1
```

It is taking that name '<indexname-{now/d}>' as a string/ alias name and gives an error

`Failed to complete action: rollover. <class 'ValueError'>: Unable to perform index rollover with alias "<indexname-{now/d}>".`

I'll suggest adding the support for date math in the alias name for rollover action in the elasticsearch curator.

Answer (score 0):

What it appears you are trying to do is to rollover an *alias* named `indexname-2021.10.28`. Is that correct? I mention this because the `name` directive is for the *alias name* rather than the index name. Additionally, using this pattern would be looking for an alias with *today's* date `{now/d}`, but the rollover conditions appear to be looking for something older than 1 day (or 1M docs, or over 50g). If that alias is older than 24 hours, the lookup will fail because it's looking for something that has likely not been created yet.

I presume you are more likely looking for an alias with a name like `index name` that points to indices that look like `indexname-YYYY.MM.dd`. Did you know that this behavior is automatic if the original index and alias combination are created with date math?

For example, if I had created this index + alias combination ***yesterday*** (and it's URLencoded for use in the dev tools console):

```
# PUT <my-index-{now/d}-000001>
PUT %3Cmy-index-%7Bnow%2Fd%7D-000001%3E
{
  "aliases": {
    "my-index": {
      "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

The results would say:

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "index" : "my-index-2021.10.27-000001"
}
```

And if I forced a rollover ***today***:

```
POST my-index/_rollover
{
  "conditions": {
    "max_age": "1d"
  }
}
```

This is the resulting output:

```
{
  "acknowledged" : true,
  "shards_acknowledged" : true,
  "old_index" : "my-index-2021.10.27-000001",
  "new_index" : "my-index-2021.10.28-000002",
  "rolled_over" : true,
  "dry_run" : false,
  "conditions" : {
    "[max_age: 1d]" : true
  }
}
```

With this behavior, it's very simple to get a date in the index name while still using default rollover behavior.

Comment: Thank you @untergeek, 
`Did you know that this behavior is automatic if the original index and alias combination are created with date math?`
Yes I know this behavior

It's the problem of Elastic curator that it doesn't support the date math in the alias name, 

If you check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/option_name.html it says "This setting is used by the alias, create_index, and snapshot, actions"  
So it means something elastic doesn't support yet.

Comment: But you're still missing my larger point. You shouldn't be naming an alias with date math and expecting it to match the name one day after the fact. This is probably not what you meant to do, but it would prevent rollover from ever being seen properly.

Comment: Additionally, aliases assigned to rollover indices absolutely expect rolled-over indices to follow a pattern where their names end with -######. If you create an index that does _not_ follow this pattern initially, the following index after rollover will have -000002 or -000001 after it, whether you created it that way or not.

Your initial example was to have an alias named with _today's_ date, but were rolling over data that was ostensibly from the previous day. This means the alias name would likely be incorrect.

Comment: For more context, I suggest logging in DEBUG mode, and possibly with `blacklist: [urllib3]` to hide the `urllib3` log messages, but reveal the Elasticsearch ones that are normally hidden. This will show a lot more that is transpiring behind the scenes.